# List with multiple derived object. How to acces the fields in the derived

Tags: c#, derived-class, base-class

Currently i'm working with a Base class called **"JourneyLeg"**. This base class has 5 derived that all inherit from the base class. two of these classes are called **"WalkingLeg"** and **"VehicleLeg"**. These 2 derived classes both contain a *"from"* and *"to"* field. The other 3 don't.

```cs
List<JourneyLeg> legs
```

I now have list with all kind of derived objects in it. Some of them are Walkingleg, some of them are vehicleleg and the rest are one of the 3 other derived classes. The list is defined as above.

I want to loop through the complete list and do actions only for the walking and vehicle objects. These actions include accessing the "*from*" and *"to"*. These 2 fields are only available in these 2 derived classes and not in the base class.

The only way i can think of is checking if it is one of the 2 derived classes and then doing the actions (See below). But this way i have so much duplicate code. I think i can't extract the duplicate code in a method because then the parameter object we give to this method would be VehicleLeg or WalkingLeg and cant be both.

```cs
case VehicleLeg vehicleLeg:
{
    var legTo = new DirectionsRequestJourneyLegsLocation(vehicleLeg.To.LatLong, vehicleLeg.To.IsVisible);
    var legFrom = new DirectionsRequestJourneyLegsLocation(vehicleLeg.From.LatLong, vehicleLeg.From.IsVisible);

    directionsRequestJourneyleg.id = vehicleLeg.Id;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.From = legFrom;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.To = legTo;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.LegArrival = vehicleLeg.From.Time.Planned;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.LegDeparture = vehicleLeg.To.Time.Planned;

    directionsRequestJourneyleg.Type = DirectionsRequestJourneyLegType.Vehicle;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.Modality = vehicleLeg.Modality;
    break;
}
case WalkingLeg walkingLeg:
{
    var legTo = new DirectionsRequestJourneyLegsLocation(walkingLeg.To.LatLong, walkingLeg.To.IsVisible);
    var legFrom = new DirectionsRequestJourneyLegsLocation(walkingLeg.From.LatLong, walkingLeg.From.IsVisible);


    directionsRequestJourneyleg.id = walkingLeg.Id;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.From = legFrom;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.To = legTo;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.LegArrival = walkingLeg.From.Time.Planned;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.LegDeparture = walkingLeg.To.Time.Planned;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.Type = DirectionsRequestJourneyLegType.Walking;
    break;
}
```

I'm probably missing something easy here. But i cant wrap my head around it. I hope someone can get me back on the right track.

Below here are the classes:

```
/// <summary>
/// JourneyLeg is the base class used to define commonalities between:
/// 
/// *VehicleLeg, WalkingLeg, TransitionLeg, AdvertisementLeg*
/// </summary>
public class JourneyLeg
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public LegType Type { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Vehicle leg model
/// </summary>
public class VehicleLeg : JourneyLeg
{
    [Required]
    public ModalityType Modality { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public LegStop From { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public LegStop To { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Walking leg model
/// </summary>
public class WalkingLeg : JourneyLeg
{
    [Required]
    public LegStop From { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public LegStop To { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the total walk time in minutes and in parenthese the distance in meters
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Better to use interface inheritance instead of class inheritance - you can have multiple interfaces on class (such as Leg and Arm can have IVehicle interface, but they have separated ILeg and IArm interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add an intermediary class that adds the `From` and `To` properties:

```
public class JourneyLeg
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public LegType Type { get; set; }
}

// You may want another name...
public class JourneyFromToLeg : JourneyLeg
{
    [Required]
    public LegStop From { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public LegStop To { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleLeg : JourneyFromToLeg 
{
    [Required]
    public ModalityType Modality { get; set; }
}

public class WalkingLeg : JourneyFromToLeg 
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So you can then use:

```
case JourneyFromToLeg fromToLeg:
{
    var legTo = new DirectionsRequestJourneyLegsLocation(fromToLeg.To.LatLong, fromToLeg.To.IsVisible);
    var legFrom = new DirectionsRequestJourneyLegsLocation(fromToLeg.From.LatLong, fromToLeg.From.IsVisible);


    directionsRequestJourneyleg.id = fromToLeg.Id;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.From = legFrom;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.To = legTo;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.LegArrival = fromToLeg.From.Time.Planned;
    directionsRequestJourneyleg.LegDeparture = fromToLeg.To.Time.Planned;

    // you may want to think a little more of this too
    if (fromToLeg is WalkingLeg)
    {
        directionsRequestJourneyleg.Type = DirectionsRequestJourneyLegType.Walking;
    }
    else
    {
        directionsRequestJourneyleg.Type = DirectionsRequestJourneyLegType.Vehicle;
        directionsRequestJourneyleg.Modality = ((VehicleLeg)fromToLeg).Modality;            
    }

    break;
}
```

You could otherwise have `IFromLeg`/`IToLeg`/`IFromToLeg` interfaces if you'd prefer to use interface inheritance

Comment: I was implementing this answer and still had problems. Reviewed my code and came to the conclusion that the list only contains the base JourneyLeg class objects. Its created in my web controller from "posted" JSON and of course there it doesn't know the derived class only the base class. I guess i have to check the fields and create a new object. Still want to check the answer as correct, this answer will definitely help the problem described above.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new class `JourneyLegFromTo` or similar that inherits `JourneyLeg`, then make `VehicleLeg` and `WalkingLeg` inherit from the new class.

Then you can reduce the code down to checking if it's a `JouneyLegFromTo` instead of the two cases, and you'll be able to access the from and two fields.

```
public class JourneyLegFromTo : JourneyLeg
{
    [Required]
    public LegStop From { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public LegStop To { get; set; }
}

public class WalkingLeg : JourneyLegFromTo 
{
    ...
}

public class VehicleLeg : JourneyLegFromTo 
{
    ...
}
```

Later on:

```
case JourneyLegFromTo journeyLegFromTo:
{
    var legTo = new DirectionsRequestJourneyLegsLocation(journeyLegFromTo.To.LatLong, journeyLegFromTo.To.IsVisible);
    var legFrom = new DirectionsRequestJourneyLegsLocation(journeyLegFromTo.From.LatLong, journeyLegFromTo.From.IsVisible);
    ...
```

Comment: Just a note: I added the full switch on my answer because the `case` ends with stuff specific to `WalkingLeg` and `VehicleLeg`